# Mediaplayer sound does not overlap

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

When you click the button it adds 5 to a sum and makes a sound.
The  problem is that when you click it repeatedly, it adds 5 but the sound does not overlap.

Please see code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_2);

    final MediaPlayer plussound = MediaPlayer.create(basic_2.this, R.raw.plus);    

    Button plus5b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    plus5b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            plussound.start();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                counterValue++;
            }
            counterdown.setText(String.valueOf(counterValue));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want the sound to overlap and play at the same time?

Comment: Yes, i want the sound to overlap

Comment: Where is it adding 5 to a sum? Once I see that I know where to place the sound to make it overlap

Comment: I only see a counter being counted until it reaches 5

Comment: It adds 5 to a text view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `MediaPlayer` can only play one sound at a time, so you need to create a new `MediaPlayer` for each sound, so create it inside the `onClick` method. Also make sure to get rid of it after the sound is played (using a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`) to avoid having memory issues.

```
Button plus5b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
plus5b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(basic_2.this, R.raw.plus);    
        // Adding an onCompletionListener to ensure the MediaPlayer releases the memory after playing
        plussound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
           }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            counterValue++;
        }
        counterdown.setText(String.valueOf(counterValue));
    }
});
```

Comment: how long is the sound? you could make a pool of mediaplayers, let's say 10 and pick one which is not playing. I'll try to make an example

Comment: @ManosRasidakis Have a try with my second version. Given the duration of the sound, it should be sufficient.

Comment: it is a class variable, so you can only see it in the activity. If you make an other activity, declare an other one in the new activity. You can use the same name.

Comment: Do you mean after clicking a bunch of times on several activities? Or straight away when starting the app?

Comment: Is there a way to clear pool after ending the activity?

Comment: you can try, in the `onPause` method, go through the pool, and for each MediaPlayer, call `mp.release(); mp = null;` then `mediaPlayerPool.clear();` An other way would be to have the MediaPlayer pool as a Static object that all activities can use, so you have only one, but this is an other architecture.

Comment: Also, not cool to take the answer tick away, my answer solved the overlapping issue :) We now have a memory management problem which could be an other question on its own. But I am willing to help you with it here.

Comment: Is the the static object way more memory consuming ?

Comment: No, you would have only one instead of one per activity. Did you try my suggestion to release and nullify all the MediaPlayers in the onPause method?

Comment: @ManosRasidakis I added a last example with a Singleton class which I think is nice. Notice the addition of an onCompletionListener on the media players that get them to release and get out of the pool at completion. I probably should have used that in the first 2 examples.

Comment: when you say get the media player manager singleton what do you mean?

Comment: I mean `mediaPlayerPool = MediaPlayerPool.getInstance(this);` gets you the instance of the `MediaManagerPool`. This class is implemented as a Singleton, that means there can only be one

Comment: It worked on one activity now i am aplying the code to other activities to see if it works

Comment: Now I think about it, the very first simple solution would probably work fine if we add the `onCompletionListener` the same way I do it in the last complex version, they would auto release themselves after playing and we don't need a pool.

Comment: I edited the first solution, I am pretty sure it would work fine too

Comment: In my code the last solution with the pool works better

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: sorry to bother you again but do you know how i can mute the sound with a button

Comment: do you mean stop it when it is playing? or not play at all when the plus5b button is pressed?

Comment: I want to give the user the option to mute the app completely

Comment: stick a boolean on your MediaPlayerPool that you set to false when the mute a button is pressed. Then in your playSound method, do nothing if the value is false.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have the sound overlay you would need the code to be the following:

```
Button plus5b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
plus5b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            counterValue++;
        }
        counterdown.setText(String.valueOf(counterValue));
        plussound.start();
    }
});
```

The reason the sound method needs to be inside the for loop and not outside of it is because when it is outside and the button is clicked it only goes off once because the action is not repeated every time the user clicks it.

Comment: Maybe i did not explain it properly but i dont want it to play 5 times the sound onclick. I want when someone clicks the button to play the sound and if the sound is still playing(from the first click) when the button is clicked again i want the sound to overlap.

Comment: Oh alright that makes sense I will change it accordingly

Comment: @ManosRasidakis so is it adding  to the textview via the counterdown.setText() line of code in the onClickListener?

Comment: Yep the adding is happening via the counterdown.setText()

Comment: @ManosRasidakis see the below answer, he is correct